# ResultSet getObject<T> convention on NULLs

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I was looking for a nice-looking way to extract a nullable value from a ResultSet, as opposite to wasNull. Documentation (API spec) guarantees that "untyped" getObject (returning Object) returns null when the column contains NULL, making the following construct valid: `(Boolean)rs.getObject(1)`.

Naturally, I would prefer to do `rs.getObject(1, Boolean.class)` - but, for some reason, for the typed overload no such guarantees are provided.

Or are they? Maybe I am just missing something? I found nothing for this particular oveload at [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) , and JDBC spec seems to overlook such overloads entirely.

So, do NULLs get converted to nulls by `rs.getObject(1, Boolean.class)`, or don't they, or is that implementation-dependent, or maybe it depends on some custom conversions defined in an application?

Comment: You should indicate what you want to ask in the title.

Comment: The API documentation of JDBC is pretty sparse, and as far as I know the same requirements apply to the typed `getObject` as to the untyped `getObject`. However, if you want an authoritative answer, you might want to post your question to the _jdbc-spec-discuss_ mailinglist.